# Find all anagram in a string how to optimize

Tags: python, anagram

Given a string s and a non-empty string p, find all the start indices of p's anagrams in s.

Example:-

- Input: s: `"cbaebabacd"` p: `"abc"`
- Output: `[0, 6]`
- Explanation:
  The substring with start index = 0 is "cba", which is an anagram of "abc".
  The substring with start index = 6 is "bac", which is an anagram of "abc".

I have written this code in Python for "Find All Anagrams in a String"
When I am running this code it is giving me message `Time exceeded`:

1) Whether my logic is correct

2) How I can optimize so that it can run faster as it is taking long time (About 1 minutes) for large input strings.

```
def anagram(s,p):
    if len(p)>len(s):
        return False
    l_s=len(s)
    l_p=len(p)
    list1=[]
    offset=l_p
    k=offset
    i=0
    while (i <= l_s):
        s4=s[i:k]
        #print ("s= "+s4)
        if sorted(p)==sorted(s4):
            list1.append(i)
        i+=1
        k=i+(offset)
    return list1
```

Comment: What is `p` supposed to do? Some explanation on what your variables are and what you want to output would be good.

Comment: did you run a profiler to see where is the hot spot?

Comment: I have already mentioned in my comment section above code regarding input and outputs for e.g. "Find All Anagrams in a String ". Input: s: "cbaebabacd" p: "abc" Output: [0, 6]. Also my program is running with correct out put. Only it is taking >1 minutes for larger input string of length >10000. So need input in terms of what changes I can do in my code to run it faster.

Comment: Please explain the variables. `p` and `s` are not really helpful names. Also, what does `[0, 6]` mean? What is `0`? What is `6`?

Comment: When you increase `i` and `k` by one, you are essentially just adding one character and removing one character in your `s4`. So you don't need to sort again, that is the bottleneck. Instead, I would maintain a dictionary.

Comment: Here are details "Given a string s and a non-empty string p, find all the start indices of p's anagrams in s." Further example:- Input:
s: "cbaebabacd" p: "abc"

Output:
[0, 6]

Explanation:
The substring with start index = 0 is "cba", which is an anagram of "abc".
The substring with start index = 6 is "bac", which is an anagram of "abc".

Comment: Your while loop can stop at `l_s - l_p`.

Comment: You don't need to calculate `sorted(p)` every time through the loop, it never changes.

Comment: Even after sorting (p) once by moving it outside the while loop I don't see improvement in its run time. Any idea how I can add logic of maintaining dictionary and exactly what I need to do after that to speed up.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to sort `p` once, since it never changes. You can do that at the beginning of the function.

You should stop the loop when you get to `i = len_s - len_p`, since the rest of the string is shorter than `p`.

```
def anagram(s,p):
    if len(p)>len(s):
        return False
    len_p = len(p)
    sorted_p = sorted(p)
    list1=[]
    for i in range(len(s) - len_p + 1):
        s4=s[i:i+len_p]
        #print ("s= "+s4)
        if sorted_p == sorted(s4):
            list1.append(i)
    return list1
```

Comment: Thanks Barmar for quick reply. When I ran your program it gave incorrect results for inputs (s="abab",p="ab") as [0, 1]. It should have been [0, 1, 2]. My program runs fine only issue is that it is slow.

Comment: Fencepost error, I was stopping 1 character too early.

Comment: Thanks Barmar. It works now. Good logic. But time wise I still see it takes about a minute. So no improvement in run time. This happens when I give s=1000 (i.e. "aaaa.........1000 number of a") and p=1000 (i.e. "aaaa.........1000 number of a")

Comment: s and p are both 1000 characters? That should only loop one time, so it equivalent to `if sorted(p) == sorted(s):`

Comment: Sorry "s" was way more than what I said .The inputs are as follows:- the number of a's in s=(aaa.........................20002 a's) and p=(aaa...................10001 a's). Answer for this one is [0, 10001]

Comment: That will do ahout 10,000 sorts of 10001 items. That's a lot of sorting, which will be slow.

Comment: As mentioned in a comment, you can optimize it by realizing that you're always removing 1 character and adding 1 character. You can insert the new character in the correctly sorted location, rather than having to redo the sort.

Comment: I could do that for you, but I think the whole point of the exercise is for you to figure out the algorithm yourself.

Comment: Thanks Barmar. I will try the suggestion.